# How to find documents in a collection with a filter on multiple combined fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is some documents as example:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566e80fcddf99fd898a11ad8"),
    "username" : "dummy_0",
    "score" : 10
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566e80fcddf99fd898a11ad9"),
    "username" : "dummy_1",
    "score" : 20
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566e80fcddf99fd898a11ada"),
    "username" : "dummy_1",
    "score" : 30
}
```

I'd like to get all the documents where the couple (username/score) doesn't exist.

For example if I select `username: dummy_1` and `score: 20` I should retrieved Object 1 and 3.

First I tried:

```
db.foobar.find({ score: { $ne: 20}, username: { $ne: 'dummy_1'}})
```

But it obviously doesn't work.

Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query as below using the logical [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

```js
db.foobar.find( { 
    $or: [ 
        { "username": { $ne: "dummy_1" } }, 
        { "score": { $ne: 20 } } 
    ] 
})
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could query as below using the logical `$or` operator.

```html
db.foobar.find( { 
    $or: [ 
        { "username": { $exists: false } }, 
        { "score": { $exists: false } } 
    ] 
})
```

It will return all the documents where the couple (username/score) doesn't exist.

Comment: @RumeshEranga Yes, sorry my mistake. Thanks for correction :)

Comment: Btw your description still says `$and`. Try editing that as  well :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "and" operator. Can you try the below one and see.

```
db.foobar.find({ $and: [{score: { $ne: 20}}, {username: { $ne: 'dummy_1'}}]})
```

Comment: Did you try the query yourself before posting the answer?